# Merge data from two tables from different SQL Server database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008, merge

I have one central and two client database that have the same structure (identity id). The application allows users to merge data of selected tables from central db with one client db at a time.

For example:

`[db_central].[table]`:

```
+-------+-------+
| id    | name  |
+-------+-------+
| 1     | A     |
| 2     | B     |
| 3     | C     |
+---------------+
```

`[db_client_1].[table]`:

```
+-------+-------+
| id    | name  |
+-------+-------+
| 3     | D     |
+---------------+
```

`[db_client_2].[table]`:

```
+-------+-------+
| id    | name  |
+-------+-------+
| 3     | E     |
+---------------+
```

Expected result after merging (twice):

`[db_central].[table]`:

```
+-------+-------+
| id    | name  |
+-------+-------+
| 1     | A     |
| 2     | B     |
| 3     | C     |
| 4     | D     |
| 5     | E     |
+---------------+
```

Currently, I'm only able to load tables from database.

[image]

When user clicks "Manual Sync" button, the app will compare and merge data of selected tables from left to right database or vice versa.

If table doesn't exist, it will create the new one. If table does exist, it will compare and merge data but I don't know what is the best solution to accomplish this task.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a simple sql query (if the databases are on the same server, or if you have a linked server between them) using `except`...

```
insert into db_central       // Target table
select name from db_client_1 // Source table
except
select name from db_central  // Target table
```

If you have to do it in Linq, then it's very similar:

```
// Get the list of names to add
var newNames = dbContext.db_client_1.Select(e => e.name).Except(dbContext.db_central.Select(e => e.name));
// Convert the names to a list of entity objects and add them.
dbContext.db_central.Add(newNames.Select(e => new db_central { name = e.name });
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This is assuming you don't want duplicates in `db_central`

Comment: I tried to execute this query `INSERT INTO [UniversityB].[dbo].[Student] SELECT [name],[day_of_birth],[address] FROM [UniversityA].[dbo].[Student] WHERE [UniversityA].[dbo].[Student].[student_id] NOT IN (SELECT [UniversityB].[dbo].[Student].[student_id] FROM [UniversityB].[dbo].[Student])` But it gave me this error: Msg 545, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Student' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column. Any ideal ?

Comment: @user1728585, It looks like one of the columns (most likely `student_id`) is an identity column, but has identity_insert on or not for replication set.  This means that you need to insert a value into that field.  However, this makes me think that replication may not be set up properly for whatever task your trying to accomplish.  I suspect that there are better ways to solve this problem.  Merge replication comes to mind.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have two columns at table in `Central Database`

1. Primary key (with identity enabled)
2. ChildKey (Primary Key of Child databases)

Primary key column in central database will take care of ordering, and chiild column will give you primary key in respective database

Comment: thanks but the problem is that tables of central and client database have the same structure and my app is not supposed to modify table structure.